# Agregar Title, Author, al documento Pdf usando iText7

Tags: pdf, dotnetcore, itextpdf

Estoy usando Itext7 para generar generar y manipular documentos Pdf con C#.
Quiero agregar propiedades al Pdf, por ejemplo *Titulo* y *Autor*.
En la documentación de iText7 no he encontrado cómo agregar las propiedades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(destHeader), new PdfWriter(pdfDest));
   
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        

int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
if (numberOfPages > 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        if (Idioma == ConstanciasLenguaje.Español())
        {                        
            doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("Página " + i + " de " + numberOfPages).SetFontSize(10), 300, 60, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
        }
        else 
        {
           doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("Page " + i + " of " + numberOfPages).SetFontSize(10), 300, 60, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0).SetFontSize(9);
        }
    }
}
        
doc.Close();
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: https://blog.conholdate.com/es/total/edit-metadata-of-pdf-files-using-csharp/#CSharp-API-to-Edit-Metadata-of-PDF-Files